# Debian Buster freezes randomly

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel

I installed Debian 10.9 KDE non-free, and it starts freezing randomly. I have restart my PC to continue my work. I think it's a kernel incompatibility issue. I didn't have any issue with `Ubuntu 20` before.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you think it's a kernel incompatibility issue, and a distribution with a newer kernel seems to have worked for you, you might want to try installing a newer kernel and a corresponding NVIDIA driver version from the [buster-backports repository.](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/)

This way, you could relatively easily go up to [kernel version 5.10](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/kernel/linux-image-5.10.0-0.bpo.3-amd64) and [NVIDIA driver version 460.73](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/kernel/nvidia-tesla-460-kernel-dkms).

Since Debian 11 is very close to becoming the new stable release, upgrading to it might actually be an even better idea.

But if you want to investigate further:

- make sure `/var/log/journal/` exists and once you reboot after a freeze, use `journalctl -b -1` to investigate the logs of the previous boot. After running the command, press upper-case <kbd>G</kbd> to go directly to the end of the log. Is there anything at the end of the log that might provide more information about the freeze?
- is it a total freeze, or just a GUI/console hang? For example, if you have the `ssh` service enabled, can you still connect to your computer via SSH from another computer when the freeze occurs?
- if it seems to be a GUI freeze only, are there any `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.*` files when rebooting after a freeze? Is there anything in those files that looks like an error message?

Comment: Good answer, however having Debian 11 in frozen state and almost out of the door in 1-3 months, I would not even bother with Debian 10 and corresponding backports.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro good point, however there might be other restrictions the original poster has not mentioned: perhaps they need the strong security support associated with the stable version? Anyway, that judgement call will be theirs to make. (In a similar situation, I would probably go with the newer release too, unless there were very strong reasons to do otherwise.)

Comment: I trust testing at this point more than Ubuntu "stable", and in fact even deploying *production* servers in the past, I made the choice on similar points in time of being near the release, and even earlier, to go with the "next" release, which I did not regret. Usually also by this point 10/the current distro is largely irrelevant, too many old stuff. Besides, you do not want to deploy a machine to be upgrading it in 1-2 months time. Also, the OP is talking about a notebook, not seeing the "strong security" need there. Plus, testing idea is even reinforced, per OP  "coming from Ubuntu"